# how can monitor many regions in xcode?

Tags: xcode, core-location, cllocationmanager, locationmanager, regions

the max of regions can be monitored in xcode is 20 region how can i monitor more then this number by monitor only closest regions ?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < [AllRegionsArray count]; i++) {
        NSArray *LongLati = [AllRegionsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        lutiuid  = [LongLati objectAtIndex:0];
        Longtuid = [LongLati objectAtIndex:1];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D centreLoc = {[lutiuid floatValue], [Longtuid floatValue]};
        CLLocationDistance regionRadius = 100.00;
        CLRegion *grRegion = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centreLoc radius:regionRadius identifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"grRegion%i",i]];

        [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:grRegion desiredAccuracy:acc];


    }
```

Comment: what do you mean? Can you elaborate & show codes?

Comment: Working on iOS or Mac OS ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the available number of regions by:

```
[CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable]
```

In the Location Awareness Programming Guide,

> You should always be judicious when specifying the set of regions to
>   monitor. Regions are a shared system resource and the total number of
>   regions available systemwide is limited. For this reason, Core
>   Location limits the number of regions that may be simultaneously
>   monitored by a single application.

Therefore, the maximum number of regions are limited & not fixed. It is shared system-wide. Referring to your question, you should re-define your regions.

Remember to implement

```
locationManager:monitoringDidFailForRegion:withError:
```

in case of any failure when adding region to be monitored.

Comment: that's another question. Ask separately.